# Excluding a link from slideToggle, jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter, slidetoggle

I am trying to build a twitter style web app. I have a code that on click shows extra content of that twit (with reply and other details). This is the jquery code:

```
$('.twit').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle(function() {});
});
```

This works just fine, but (like on twitter) I would like when the user click on the username(of the creator) the slideToggle does not go off (the details not to show), I tried this:

```
$('.twit').not('.username').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle(function() {});
});
```

Here is the html:

```
<div id="twit_id_{$twits[i].TID}" class="twit">

    <a href="user.php?id={$twits[i].USERID}" class="username">{$twits[i].display_name}</a>

</div>

<div class="details" style="display:none;">

    <!--details-->   

</div>
```

Comment: can you post some html as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.twit:not(".username")').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle(function() {});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on("click",".username",function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Change your div structure. As <a> tag is child of .twit div it causes this problem. Move this tag outside div. After that your problem will solve automatically.